# summation proof of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(2i - (\frac{1}{2})^{i+1} \right)$

Tags: proof-verification, summation

Does this look right?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(2i - (\frac{1}{2})^{i+1} \right)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{2})^{i+1}$$
$$2\sum_{i=1}^{n} i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{2})^{i+1}$$ 
$$2\frac{(n)(n+1)}2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{2})^{i+1}$$ 
$$n^2 + n - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{2})^{i-1+2}$$ 
$$n^2 + n - (\frac12)^2 \times \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{2})^{i-1} $$ 
$$n^2 + n - \frac14 \times \frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{1-\frac{1}{2}} $$ 
$$n^2 + n - \frac14 \times [2 \times (1-\frac12^n)] $$ 
$$n^2 + n - \frac12 \times (1-\frac12^n) $$

Comment: Your 6th line is confusing me, but your 7th seems to get back on rack.

Comment: @Zain Patel yeah me too I was working with another student on this and that line also had me wondering what was going on I think it must be a copying error. Probably best to delete that line? Is the solution correct?

Comment: Apart from the offending line, everything is top notch.

Comment: The partial sum calculated by Wolfram Alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=infinite+sum+of+(2n+-+(1%2F2)%5E(n%2B1)) and your result https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E2%2Bn%E2%88%921%2F2%C3%97(1%E2%88%92(1%2F2)%5En) match term by term.

Comment: Thanks @Zain-Patel I removed it so for history purposes I had accidentally in line 6 this:  $n^2 + n - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{2})^{i-1} - \frac12$

Comment: minor proofreading: in line 6: $\frac{1^2}{2}$ should be $\left(\frac12\right)^2$